# Python EEL: Changing button label during script running

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

I have a script that compiles a bunch of files from diferent directories into one xlsx sheet.
I am creating a front-end to it so I can share it with my coworkers, and while I have print statements throughout my code I want some feedback on my GUI.

I need the button to change the label during code execution, this is what I tried:

```
function getstarted(){
    document.getElementById("buttonstart").value="Running...";
    eel.myfunc();
    document.getElementById("buttonstart").value="Done!";
}
```

This of course isn't working, since javascript isn't waiting for my eel function to finish processing to change the value again.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the function asynchronous, you can ask to await the response from Eel.

```
async function getstarted(){
    document.getElementById("buttonstart").value="Running...";
    await eel.myfunc()();
    document.getElementById("buttonstart").value="Done!";
}
```

If you don't want to use an asynchronous method, another option is to put the code that runs after into another method that Eel calls when it is done.

```
function getstarted() {
    document.getElementById("buttonstart").value="Running...";
    eel.myfunc()(getstarted2);
}

function getstarted2() {
    document.getElementById("buttonstart").value="Done!";
}
```

Comment: For some reason the async method isn't working, but the second one is running perfect.
Thanks!

Comment: @the_clash_1976 make sure that `eel.myfunc()();` has two sets of parentheses. You're welcome!